# Can't Run as TestNg in Eclipse and encountered the following Error

Tags: java, selenium, frameworks, testng

[Trying to Install/Update TestNG from MarketPlace, received an error as given in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCajD.png)
strong text

Can't run as TestNG in Eclipse

Comment: Hey, what version of eclipse are you using? i already have installed testNG in eclipse 2020-06.

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen 4.7

Comment: Can't you change your eclipse version? I mean, this would be the easiest solution.